# "Les morts gouvernent les vivants" - "The Dead govern the living" - Auguste Comte

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Living in France & participating in traditional Latin masses, I'm only vaguely familiar with some Latin in very specific contexts. I was looking to translate the sentence "*Les Morts gouvernents les vivants / The dead govern the living*" from an author I appreciate, Auguste Comte -
I instinctively thought the words I would need were relative to "*Vivo / Dominor / Morior*" which you can hear the variations of often at the church.

After doing more research, I think I found the present & plural version of Dominor for this specific sentence which might be "Dominantur", Mortuos or perhaps Mortui for "the dead" & viventes,ium ? for "the living".

Which would give me something in the area of "**Mortuis/Mortuos Dominantur Viventes/Vivens**"

Am I far off? Close?
Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You are spot on with the pair *mortui* and *viventes* -- the dead and the living. I am not so sure about *dominari*, as the meaning is closer to "be dominant (in some area or respect)"; it would seem more natural to me to use *imperare*. If *imperare* has no direct object (or AcI, *ut* clause, etc.), it just means "govern, rule over" with the governed party in the dative. That would be *viventibus*. Since the dead are the subject, they're in the nominative, which is *mortui*. (*Mortuos* would be the accusative.)

Thus we get:

> Mortui imperant viventibus.

(Although I would personally be partial to *Imperant viventibus mortui.*)

Comment: Strangely no "Viventes invidebunt mortuis" anywhere on the web 

Comment: Thank you M Koppehel, I might have jumped too fast on my conclusion to use Dominari, hearing it often during the Novus Ordo : "Domine". Imperare makes perfect sense, I hadn't thought of it. So it would be Mortui, not Mortuis, is it because it's considered a "single group" ?
I'm just stepping into Latin, excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @Joseph the word *Domine* that you are liable to encounter frequently in Christian liturgy is the vocative of *Dominus*, i.e. Lord (le Seigneur), used when addressing God. A single dead is *mortuus*, multiple dead people are *mortui*, and *mortuis* is the same, but with a different case ending, which, however,  is not called for in this context. See them all [here](https://latin.cactus2000.de/noun/shownoun_en.php?n=mortuus).

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I've been doing much necessary reading since yesterday & it makes more sense now - May I ask you why you would personally prefer that second form you suggested ? Is it more correct grammatically ?

Comment: @Joseph both are equally correct (otherwise I would of course have said so), it is just a matter of taste. I cannot exactly explain why, maybe because the "surprise" comes last. The first form is closer to Comte's original, though.